# Custom meta box shown when template is chosen

Tags: metabox, page-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Toggle admin metabox based upon chosen page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18122/toggle-admin-metabox-based-upon-chosen-page-template)

Is this possible to change editor screen immediately after someone picks some template from the drop down?
I need a metabox shown only when page template is `page-portfolio.php`. I know I can use this code:

`$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;`

`$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);`

And than add my boxes using `if` statements. The problem is it doesn't work immediately. Is this even possible without very complex coding to do "catch" moment when user changes templates list without saving?

Comment: Are you using custom post types?

Comment: @westondeboer Nope, forgot about this information. Right now I'm working with normal pages.

Comment: ups, after publishing the answer, I saw the possible duplicate warning... the link Stephen Harris provides does the script enqueuing the proper way

Comment: @StephenHarris Yeah Stephen, thank You. That's duplicate and there is my solution in question you provided. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the plugin [Advanced Custom Field](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) does that.
Checking [its code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/advanced-custom-fields/trunk/js/input-ajax.js), I saw that he deals with this issue using jQuery.
Using it as reference, I think this should work for you:

```
/* 
 * Change Meta Box visibility according to Page Template
 *
 * Observation: this example swaps the Featured Image meta box visibility
 *
 * Usage:
 * - adjust $('#postimagediv') to your meta box
 * - change 'page-portfolio.php' to your template's filename
 * - remove the console.log outputs
 */

add_action('admin_head', 'wpse_50092_script_enqueuer');

function wpse_50092_script_enqueuer() {
    global $current_screen;
    if('page' != $current_screen->id) return;

    echo <<<HTML
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

            /**
             * Adjust visibility of the meta box at startup
            */
            if($('#page_template').val() == 'page-portfolio.php') {
                // show the meta box
                $('#postimagediv').show();
            } else {
                // hide your meta box
                $('#postimagediv').hide();
            }

            // Debug only
            // - outputs the template filename
            // - checking for console existance to avoid js errors in non-compliant browsers
            if (typeof console == "object") 
                console.log ('default value = ' + $('#page_template').val());

            /**
             * Live adjustment of the meta box visibility
            */
            $('#page_template').live('change', function(){
                    if($(this).val() == 'page-portfolio.php') {
                    // show the meta box
                    $('#postimagediv').show();
                } else {
                    // hide your meta box
                    $('#postimagediv').hide();
                }

                // Debug only
                if (typeof console == "object") 
                    console.log ('live change value = ' + $(this).val());
            });                 
        });    
        </script>
HTML;
}
```