# Hide metabox dependant on page template chosen

Tags: jquery, admin, metabox, wp-admin

I'm using the following [JQuery script from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18122/toggle-admin-metabox-based-upon-chosen-page-template) to toggle the display of metaboxes dependant on the Page Template selected. The example below shows the **featured image** metabox when the **default** template is selected:

```
(function($){
$(function() {

    $('#page_template').change(function() {
        $('#postimagediv').toggle($(this).val() == 'default');
    }).change();

});
})(jQuery);
```

My possibly simple question is... How do I get this code to only show the featured image box for my Page Template entitled: **Services**?

I have tried simply changing the `'default'` to '`Services'` but no luck.

Comment: [You can find a solution to your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27348256/1922144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` is not the same thing that you see when you look at the toggle. That part is for humans. To see the value you have to look at the source of the page. If you have a template created by `template.contact.php` the `value` in that box would be `template.contact.php`, so it looks like the `value` is the `php` file name.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the select is setted to **the file name** so, assuming youf template file is `services.php`

```
jQuery().ready(function($) {

var $featImgDiv = $('#postimagediv');

$('#page_template').change(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'services.php' ) {
      $featImgDiv.show();
    } else {
       $featImgDiv.hide();
    }
}).change();

});
```

Comment: Sorry G. M I tried s_ha_dum's responce first and it worked, as far as I can see your responce is equally amazing however, if I could tick you both I would!

Comment: When I aswered @s_ha_dum answer was not there (or I would not have answered), I think we answer at the same time (now I see _answered 17 mins ago_ for both)